# LibGDX + Box2D | Camera too big

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I use one camera at the moment to draw the Box2DDebugRenderer and one for drawing the map from the tmx. file. My problem is that, although the cameras have the SAME definition. The camera that is used for drawing the map is way too big on the screen.

SCREENSHOT Of the Problem:

[image]

Definition for box2dCam:

```
b2dCam = new OrthographicCamera();
b2dCam.setToOrtho(false, Game.getWidth() / PPM, Game.getHeight() / PPM);
b2dCam.update();
```

Definition for regular Camera:

```
cam = new OrthographicCamera();
cam.setToOrtho(false, Game.getWidth() / PPM, Game.getHeight() / PPM);
cam.update();
```

PPM (pixels per meter) is 32.

Code Game-class (regular camera is getting defined there!):

http://pastebin.com/FcCD5SLZ

Code for Play-GameState (box2dCam get's defined and also both cams get moved to player position):

http://pastebin.com/FcCD5SLZ

Anybody has any idea why that happens?

Comment: SCREENSHOT OF THE PROBLEM:

http://i.imgur.com/B4eaz3r.png

(The brown surface is just the left bottom corner of the Map.)

Comment: have you tried decreasing pixels per meter for the map camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition for box2dCam:

```
b2dCam = new OrthographicCamera();
b2dCam.setToOrtho(false, Game.getWidth() / PPM, Game.getHeight() / PPM);
b2dCam.update();
```

Definition for regular Camera:

```
cam = new OrthographicCamera();
cam.setToOrtho(false, Game.getWidth(), Game.getHeight()); // <--
cam.update();
```

That's how it should be. Don't divide the tiled map's camera's viewport by the PPM ratio, since here you want it to be 1 unit = 1 px.

Comment: That does the trick. But it is still a bit off. Looks like the camera has it's origin in the middle of the screen. http://i.imgur.com/ijiWtvj.png

Comment: Yes. Where else would it have its origin?

Comment: That is true. But why is the box2d camera dowsn't have it's Origin in the middle of the screen?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by origin? The origin is always at (0, 0). The center of the viewport of the camera is by default the center of the screen. You can set the *position* of your cameras to whatever you want. `b2dCam.position.set(player.getPosition()); cam.position.set(player.getPosition().cpy.scl(PPM))`. Note that you have to scale the position for the "pixel" camera now.

Comment: Thx! Perfect.  But on small note: It is ".cpy().scl(PPM)" not ".cpy.scl(PPM)". Nontheless it works now :)